# why does this cast require no bridging under ARC?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

Why does casting a CGImageRef to an object pointer require no memory management info (__bridge etc.)? For example, if *image* is of type UIImage *, and *layer* is a UIView's underlying layer, then the following line of code does not elicit any complaints from the compiler:

```
layer.content = (id)[image CGImage];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> The Compiler Handles CF Objects Returned From Cocoa Methods
>
> The compiler understands Objective-C methods that return Core Foundation
> types follow the historical Cocoa naming conventions ([see Advanced
> Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i)). For example, the compiler knows
> that, in iOS, the CGColor returned by the CGColor method of UIColor is
> not owned. You must still use an appropriate type cast, as illustrated
> by this example...

(OK, not quite cocoa-touch, but hey!).

Because CGImage returns a CoreFoundation object, a `__bridge` cast isn't required.

Comment: A bigger company once asked me to join their mobile "Cocoa only" team... It seems like no one really cares about the `cocoa` and `cocoa-touch` differences and just call everything Cocoa (even ObjC), its a shame though that this apparently also happens at Apple.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, ARC does not handle CF objects except those that are returned by a Cocoa method?

Comment: Well, the first half is true: ARC does not control CF objects, but the Cocoa methods part was about CF objects following the cocoa naming protocol.

Comment: Also, seems that the conversion to id of a CF type returned by a Cocoa method has to take place immediately after the method returns the CF type (in the same line of code in fact), otherwise bridging will be required as usual; i.e. you can't release the CF type "into the wild":     CGImageRef imageCG = (CGImageRef)[im CGImage]; self.layer.contents = (id)imageCG; // won't work. But I suppose that makes sense since the compiler can't be held responsible for what you  any retains and releases you might do on your object before typing it to id. (I think...)

Comment: @CodeFi: which CF objects don't follow the Cocoa naming protocol?

Comment: Well, all CF objects in ObjC follow the [Old Cocoa Naming Conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html), which is more of a memory management thing than a naming thing.